# Сортировка словаря в словаре

Tags: python-3.x, сортировка, словари

День добрый! Есть словарь такого типа:

```
example = {
    'f': {
        'ds': 5,
        'nb': 8,
    },
    'a': {
        'sd': -5,
        'vx': 0,
        'mhj': 455,
    },
    'n': {
        'we': 12,
        'mf': 9,
        'jk': 2,
    }
}
```

Как наиболее быстро и эффективно отсортировать его в лексикографическом порядке(как по внешним, так и по внутренним ключам)?
Иными словами, чтобы он превратился вот в такой:

```
example = {
    'a': {
        'mhj': 455,
        'sd': -5,
        'vx': 0,
    },
    'f': {
        'ds': 5,
        'nb': 8
    },
    'n': {
        'jk': 2,
        'mf': 9,
        'we': 12,
    }
}
```

Для сортировки внешних ключей использую данную конструкцию:
`example = dict(sorted((example.items()), key = lambda elem: elem[0]))`
А вот как одновременно отсортировать ещё и внутренние, я не понимаю

Comment: Словарь в питоне, это неупорядоченная коллекция. Ее нельзя отсортировать.

Comment: @Alexey Trukhanov, зато его можно превратить в другой тип данных, отсортировать и снова сделать словарём(что в моей строчке кода и происходит)

Comment: После сортировки внешних ключей примени в цикле тот же код для внутренних

Comment: @Эникейщик, а есть способ обойтись без цикла?

Comment: Да наверняка можно придумать, только зачем

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov начиная с питона 3.7 — можно (хотя скорее всего не нужно)

Comment: @andreymal да, уже почитал, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте, например, рекурсию. Так можно сортировать словари любой вложенности.

```
def dsort(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            d[k] = dsort(v)
    return dict(sorted(d.items()))

print(dsort(example))
```

```
{'a': {'mhj': 455, 'sd': -5, 'vx': 0}, 'f': {'ds': 5, 'nb': 8}, 'n': {'jk': 2, 'mf': 9, 'we': 12}}
```